# How to Hot Encode with Pandas without combining rows levels

Tags: python, pandas, categorization

I have created a really big dataframe in `pandas` like similar to the following:

```
    0   1
user        
0   product4    product0
1   product3    product1
```

I want to use something, like `pd.get_dummies()`, in such a way that the final `df` would be like:

```
    product0    product1    product2    product3  product4
user                
0   1   0   0   0   1
1   0   1   0   1   0
```

instead of getting the following from `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
    0_product3  0_product4  1_product0  1_product1
user                
0   0   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   1
```

In summary, I do not want that the rows are combined into the binary columns.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use `reindex` with `get_dummies`

```
In [539]: dff = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')

In [540]: s = dff.columns.str[-1].astype(int)

In [541]: cols = 'product' + pd.RangeIndex(s.min(), s.max()+1).astype(str)

In [542]: dff.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0)
Out[542]:
      product0  product1  product2  product3  product4
user
0            1         0         0         0         1
1            0         1         0         1         0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='') # remove prefix from dummy column names and underscore
df = df.sort_index(axis=1) # order data by column names
```

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.

Comment: Actually, if I increase the number of rows and products, this does not solve the problem. There will be columns labels with repeated names. Your solutions seems to remove the prefix, but the combination of rows and columns will persist.